# how to make a laravel project on a path of other laravel project?

Tags: php, laravel, apache, centos

I have 2 laravel project : `project1` and `project2`. `project1` already online in https://mystore.com and I want `project2` is in https://mystore.com/v2. In my Virtual Machine I use CentOS as the OS and Apache as web service. In /etc/httpd/config/httpd.conf here's my settings :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName laravel.example.com

       # Project 1
       DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mystore/public
       <Directory /var/www/html/mystore/public>
              AllowOverride All
       </Directory>
       ProxyPass /socket http://localhost:3000
       ProxyPassReverse /socket http://localhost:3000
       RewriteEngine On

        # Project 2
        Alias /v2 /var/www/html/v2/public
        <Directory /var/www/html/v2/public>
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

And my route `web.php` is like this :

```
Route::redirect('/v2', '/v2/login');

Route::get('formpenerimapengaduan', [FormPenerimaPengaduan::class, 'index'])->name('formpenerimapengaduan.index');
Route::post('formpenerimapengaduan', [FormPenerimaPengaduan::class, 'store'])->name('formpenerimapengaduan.store');
Route::get('persetujuan/show/{uuid}', [PersetujuanController::class, 'show'])->name('persetujuan.show');
Route::post('persetujuan', [PersetujuanController::class, 'store'])->name('persetujuan.store');
Route::get('persetujuan/donepelayanan/{uuid}', [PersetujuanController::class, 'donepelayanan'])->name('persetujuan.done');
Route::get('blankpage', [DashboardController::class, 'blankpage'])->name('blankpage');

Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::get('dashboard', [DashboardController::class, 'index'])->name('dashboard');
Route::get('logactivity/index/', [LogActivityControler::class, 'index'])->name('logactivity');
});

require __DIR__.'/auth.php';
```

I use breeze too. Now when I go to https://mystore.com it's works but https://mystore.com/v2 it's return `404 not found`